# SQL combine two columns if data is the same in result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have the following SQL:

```
;
WITH CTE_Totals AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      CASE WHEN LoginName = Letter1SentBy
        THEN LoginName
      WHEN LoginName = Letter2SentBy
        THEN LoginName END AS Logonuser,
      sum(CASE WHEN Letter1SentDate = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()) / 7, 0)
        THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)      AS MondayL1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Letter2SentDate = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()) / 7, 0)
        THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)      AS MondayL2


    FROM MainCase
      WITH ( NOLOCK ) LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Left OUTER JOIN
    letters_sent WITH (NOLOCK) ON   MainCase.casekey = letters_sent.casekey
users WITH (NOLOCK) ON Maincase.userCaseNo = users.userCaseNo

GROUP BY LoginName, Letter1SentBy, Letter2SentBy
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  Logonuser,
  sum(MondayL1 + MondayL2) AS total
FROM CTE_Totals
GROUP BY Logonuser, CTE_Totals.MondaytL1, CTE_Totals.MondayL2
ORDER BY Logonuser ASC
```

what i am trying to achieve is :- originally i had 2 sql querys, the first to sum all letter1's sent by a user on a particular day the second to sum all letter2's sent by a user on a particular day. i want to combine both queries into 1. so i have the user name and the total of letter 1 and 2s sent.

**Maincase** Table contains data such as the 
**LoginName**

**letters_sent** table contains fields 
**Letter1SentBy, Letter1Senton (date/time field), Letter2SentBy, letter2senton (dat/time field)**

the user on the case can be different to the user who sent letter 1 and who sent letter 2 i want to find the total of letters 1 and 2 sent per user.

my issue is the user sending the letter is stored in a different field. i have tried to combine this in my above query but im getting the following results:-

- Billy  1
- Billy  6
- Bob    5
- Bob    2

if the person who sent letter 1 = the person that sent letter 2 i wouldlike results to show as

- Billy  7
- Bob    7

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: sorry dont quite undertand - i thought i had given data and desired results?

Comment: . . You showed a complex query and some results.  We have no idea what the base data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Your final part of the query should be like..

```
SELECT
Logonuser,
sum(MondayL1 + MondayL2) AS total
FROM CTE_Totals
GROUP BY Logonuser
ORDER BY Logonuser ASC
```

That should group by the Logonuser name and sum the overall value as total.